# explanation for networkx code python

Tags: python, networkx

I am new to coding python. I am hoping to modify this code to develop a bipartite two mode version.  It is code from networkx used to make a geometrci random graph.  I have got to grips with most of this function but I am having trouble understanding exactly what lines 94 to 99 are doing.  I understand while, zip and nodes.pop() but other parts are confusing for a newbie.  Can anyone help with an explanation for what this part of the code is doing more than the general # description given ?

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.name="Random Geometric Graph"
G.add_nodes_from(range(n)) 
if pos is None:
    # random positions
    for n in G:
        G.node[n]['pos']=[random.random() for i in range(0,dim)]
else:
    nx.set_node_attributes(G,'pos',pos) 
# connect nodes within "radius" of each other
# n^2 algorithm, could use a k-d tree implementation
nodes = G.nodes(data=True)
while nodes:             #line94
    u,du = nodes.pop()
    pu = du['pos']
    for v,dv in nodes:
        pv = dv['pos']
        d = sum(((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(pu,pv))) #line99
        if d <= radius**2:
            G.add_edge(u,v)
return G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nodes = [some list]
while nodes:
  a = nodes.pop()
  for b in nodes:
    # do something
```

This piece of code is a quite frequently seen idiom to combine every node with every other node exactly *once* (so the order of `a` and `b` shouldn't matter for the operation performed in the `# do something` part).

It works because the empty list is considered a falsy value in the condition of the `while` loop, while non-empty lists are considered boolean true.

```
d = sum(((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(pu,pv)))
```

This line computes the square of the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) of the two vectors `pu` and `pv`. This is best demonstrated by taking it apart:

```
>>> pu = (6,6,6)
>>> pv = (1,3,7)
>>> zip(pu, pv)
[(6, 1), (6, 3), (6, 7)]
>>> [(a-b) for a,b in zip(pu, pv)]
[5, 3, -1]
>>> [(a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(pu, pv)]
[25, 9, 1]
>>> sum((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(pu, pv))
35
```

In the last step, we don't use a list comprehension any more, because we don't need a list. `sum` just needs the values in some iterable form, so we use a generator expression instead.

Comment: minor correction: `d` is the *square* of the Euclidean distance.

Comment: @Avaris: Very true, it computes the term inside the root :)

Comment: Thank you very much this had really cleared some things out.  If possible may i ask one final thing.  I an not sure where exactly the 

    u,du = nodes.pop()
    pu = du['pos']

comes from and whats happening.  I thought i did but now i see your answer im not so sure.  
best wishes

Comment: @user: pop() removes the last element from a list and returns it (though the position is irrelevant). `pu = du['pos']` just extracts a value from the node and assigns it a simpler name.